# VBA Function in Excel Returning VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I've plenty long excel formula like this

```
IF(ISNUMBER(E6),IF(E6<standard_hour,0,IF(((E6-standard_hour)*24*60)>90,2,CEILING(((E6-standard_hour)*24*60)/30*0.5,0.5))),VLOOKUP(E6,Refer,2,FALSE))
```

Because I use this formula a lot in spreadsheet, I decide to make a custom function for it. This is the function

```
Function morning_check(start_hour)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")

    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(start_hour) Then
        If start_hour < sheet.Range("E1").Value Then
            morning_check = 0
        Else
            If ((start_hour - sheet.Range("E1").Value) * 24 * 60 > 90) Then
                morning_check = 2
            Else
                morning_check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(((start_hour - sheet.Range("E1")) * 24 * 60) / 30 * 0.5, 0.5)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        morning_check = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(start_hour, sheet.Range("Refer"), 2, False)
    End If

End Function
```

The input of this function could be string (example : "TS") or time (example : 07:00)

Using String as Input, this function work correctly, but when I using time it just throw #Value!

Comment: Which line is the source of the error? Excel should highlight it if you select Debug.

Comment: Its highlight the first line

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from the following lines:

```
Set standard_hour = TimeValue(sheet.Cells("E1"))
Set user_hour = TimeValue(start_hour)
```

`Set` in VBA is used for object creation, while you are simply trying to set a variable. This is why you're getting an "Object Required" error.

Just drop the word `Set` and you should be able to get on with your debugging.

As a matter of investigation (if your copy of Excel behaved as mine did), Excel highlighted the first line in yellow (which was not helpful), but it also automatically selected the text `standard_hour` (which identified the location on the problem).

Comment: Hi, I edit my code, and now it don't throw the error again, but it still not working for non string (first branch of IF)

Comment: Just ignore, everything work fine now, At the last step I forgot to format my Cell :D. Anyway, thank you for the explanation. This is my first time using VBA